# How to create different stages or environments in single serverless.yml file using serverless framework?

Tags: serverless

I am new to using serverless framework ,I wanted to create three different environments dev,Qa,prod. How do i create in single serverless.yml file ? The provider is AWS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a `stage` CLI option that can be interpolated wherever needed in your `serverless.yml` file. For example, take the following CLI command:

```
serverless --stage dev deploy
```

This can be accessed in `serverless.yml` with `${opt:stage}`. I usually include this under `provider`:

```
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage}
```

Then you can get the value of the `stage` option anywhere in `serverless.yml` using `${self:provider.stage}`.

When lambdas are deployed, their ARNs are automatically constructed with prefixes of the `service` name (as defined by the `service` key in `serverless.yml`), the stage, and the lambda name, like the following:

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:010101010101:function:myservice-dev-mylambdaname
```

So you can simply run the deploy CLI command for the other two stages/environments you want, and you'll have a set of separate resources for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

While @223seneca's answer is correct, the recommended option is to use `${sls:stage}` instead. This is shorthand for `${opt:stage, self:provider.stage, "dev"}`, as described in the offical doco at https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#referencing-serverless-core-variables
This allows for cases where you use the `provider` block to always have a specific `stage`, as well as supporting normal usage of passing in the `stage`.